# Adding/Importing a ready coded (AboutUs) page into Joomla

Tags: php

I am busy converting a HTML website into a Joomla temaplate, I got some help doing the home page (index.php), but now the menu items are not linking anywhere. I have a ready coded AboutUs.php page, which I want to important into Joomla and link to the 'About Us' menu item.

Can this be done in the similar way as it is done with the index.php file? Can I maybe upload the file via FTP and link it somehow in Joomla?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Usually "About Us" pages are static, so I prefer to create an article and link it to the menu.

Comment: Yes you can, but is not the efficient approach, as you are bypassing the real CMS capabilities. Follow Lodder's suggestions and put yourself in the mood of learning about Joomla. You will be more than thankful later on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I did this for a contact.php file. Here are two methods:

1) Just go in administrator/menu and select your menu there. Then click on new, and select the menu type "system link/external link".
Then in the link in the link feild.

2) Alternatively ( abit more complicate but that way you have access to your php via the backend), you can also install the modules "[Jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/1023?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo0OiJqdW1pIjt9)" and "[Module Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/6402)". Then create a new  Jumi module, copy/paste your php the the Code written field. Create a new article, add the tag {module ID} (replace ID by your module ID number) and link your menu About Us to this new article.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the menu items are not linking anywhere is because when I set them up for you that day, I set the parents/dropdowns **type** to **Text Separators**.

All your need to do is open a menu item in the Menu Manager, and set the **type** to something else, such as **Single Article**. You can select the article you would like it to link to.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi mate thanks for all the help by the way, learning a great deal here, can you just paste a load of HTML/PHP code in an article?????  because I have an already done AboutUs.php which I converted from html I read somewhere that I can make a custom HTML module, paste the code there, then make an article, link the module to the article and link the module to a menu item.

Comment: @YanOvtchinikov - I think you are misunderstanding what a CMS is. It's a content management system. You do not create PHP pages, you create articles with content and assign them or a different component to the menu item. When that menu item is clicked, it will direct you to the assigned component. There **are** plugins that will allow you to add custom PHP to your articles but just remember that there are extensions that can be used which save you having to create your own stuff. Please read the Joomla Documentation for more info

Comment: Before you start a task, stop, have a coffee, sit down and think about how your are going to approach it. The Joomla Docs will honestly give you loads of useful information about how to do things ;) So if you want an "About Us" page, simply create a new Article, save it, then in the Menu Manager, assigned the "About Us" menu item to your newly created article...simple